# Como simplificar o processo de classificação de uma hash baseada em values

Tags: ruby, classificação, hash

Opa, sou novo no site, e também no Ruby.

Minha dúvida é: Existe uma forma mais eficiente de classificar uma hash de acordo com os valores?

Fiz o código abaixo, porém tenho certeza que não é a forma mais eficiente.

```
agents = {"pedro" => 7, "lucas" => 12, "gabriel" => 15, "tadeu" => 4, "denis" => 22, "fabio" => 0}

agents_array = agents.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse

agents_array.map { |element| element.rotate! 1 }

agents_ordered = Hash.new

agents_array.each do |element|
    agents_ordered[element[1]] = agents[element[1]]
end

puts agents_ordered.inspect
```

> **Input:** agents = {"pedro" => 7, "lucas" => 12, "gabriel" => 15, "tadeu"
> => 4, "denis" => 22, "fabio" => 0}
>
> **Outup Esperado:** agents_ordered = {"denis"=>22, "gabriel"=>15,
> "lucas"=>12, "pedro"=>7, "tadeu"=>4, "fabio"=>0}

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de fazer a classificação?

Answer (score 1):

Este problema pode ser resolvido utilizando de forma simples utilizando apenas as bibliotecas disponíveis no ruby.

```
agents = {"pedro" => 7, "lucas" => 12, "gabriel" => 15, "tadeu" => 4, "denis" => 22, "fabio" => 0}.sort_by{|key, value| value }.reverse.to_h
=> {"denis"=>22, "gabriel"=>15, "lucas"=>12, "pedro"=>7, "tadeu"=>4, "fabio"=>0}
```

Vale notar que você só sentirar problemas de performance quando o volume de dados é zaroavelmente alto. Segue uma simples comparação de performance:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'securerandom'

data = {}

1000000.times do |d|
  data[SecureRandom.hex] = rand(1..1000000)
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  #implementação mais rápida
  x.report do
    data.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.reverse.to_h
  end

  # um outra alternativa
  x.report do
    data.sort {|l, r| r.first <=> l.first }.to_h
  end

  # sua implementação
  x.report do
    agents_array = data.sort_by { |k, v| v }.reverse

    agents_array.map { |element| element.rotate! 1 }

    agents_ordered = Hash.new

    agents_array.each do |element|
      agents_ordered[element[1]] = data[element[1]]
    end
  end
end

   user     system      total        real
3.510000   0.010000   3.520000 (  3.539540)
7.150000   0.010000   7.160000 (  7.167365)
4.450000   0.010000   4.460000 (  4.457346)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplificar seu código usando somente métodos nativos:

```
agents = {"pedro" => 7, "lucas" => 12, "gabriel" => 15, "tadeu" => 4, "denis" => 22, "fabio" => 0}
# => {"pedro"=>7, "lucas"=>12, "gabriel"=>15, "tadeu"=>4, "denis"=>22, "fabio"=>0}

agents_ordered = agents.sort_by(&:last).reverse.to_h
# => {"denis"=>22, "gabriel"=>15, "lucas"=>12, "pedro"=>7, "tadeu"=>4, "fabio"=>0}
```